# Mounting MicroSDXC to PC causes drive icon to light up, but no card is detected

Tags: micro-sd-card

As the title states, plugging in a MicroSDXC card directly into the MicroSDCX slot on my PC's card reader causes that drive's icon to light up, but no card is actually detected. Here's some additional info:

1. Plugging a different MicroSD card into the same slot works. The card is recognized.
2. Plugging in the same MicroSDXC card (the one that doesn't work) into an SD adapter and then plugging that into the normal-sized SD card (on the same reader) works!

So the only fail case is a specific card in a specific slot. Changing the card works, changing the slot works. I don't know what to make of this.

Card reader: PRO-55U

Card: SanDisk Ultra 64GB MicroSDXC

OS: Windows 7 64-bit

Note that the card reader slot is explicitly labeled "MicroSDXC", so it should be compatible

Comment: Does another MicroSDXC card work when plugged it?  Is it also 64GB?  Some card readers bomb out when the card capacity is > 32 GB.

Comment: How do you check if the card got recognized? If you are just checking for a new drive letter in Windows Explorer - do also check in the Computer Management/Storage/Disk Management. Sometimes card reader slots do not get a drive letter assigned to them automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the [PRO-55U](http://www.atechflash.com/AtechFlash_Product_PRO-55U_support.htm) doesn't support the SDXC card.

From the maker's [User Guide](http://www.atechflash.com/Users%20Guide/PRO-55U_UsersGuide.pdf), page 9/19:

> ..., Secure Digital(SDHC), miniSD(HC), microSD(HC), ...

In the manual I also don't see the MicroSDXC port, so can you confirm this is the correct device?